# Creating an interface for an array datatype

Tags: typescript

Using an financial API, I can only obtain and send the following datatype:

Here is an example:

```
const dataset:OhlcCandleStick[]  = [
    [
        1519396200000,
        173.67,
        175.65,
        173.54,
        175.5
    ],
    [
        1519655400000,
        176.35,
        179.39,
        176.21,
        178.97
       ],
    ...
 ]
```

I want to use Typescript type checking for this data structure

So I am trying to create an interface

```
interface OhlcCandleStick {
    [datetime:0]: number,
    [open:1]: number,
    [high:2]: number,
    [low:3]: number
    [close:3]: number
}
```

But this does not work.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `[datetime:0]` and so on? And what does "this does not work" mean? Be specific.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const dataset:Array<number[]>  = [
    [
        1519396200000,
        173.67,
        175.65,
        173.54,
        175.5
    ],
    [
        1519655400000,
        176.35,
        179.39,
        176.21,
        178.97
       ],
 ]
```

Or If you want to use the interface, have a look on this

```
const dataset: ICandle[] = [
    {
        datetime: 1519396200000,
        open: 173.67,
        high: 175.65,
        low: 173.54,
        close: 175.5
    },
    {
        datetime: 1519655400000,
        open: 176.35,
        high: 179.39,
        low: 176.21,
        close: 178.97
    },
]

interface ICandle { 
    datetime: number;
    open: number;
    high: number;
    low: number;
    close: number;
}
```